# Android : Converting Uri to Url

Tags: android

I am trying to check if I have selected image or video from Mediastore. For that I am trying to check mime type. I am not sure how to convert Uri to Url.

This is the code :

```
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PICK_MEDIA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {

        Uri uri = data.getData();
        Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Postactivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("Uri", uri);

        String mimetype = getMimeType(uri.toString());

        if (mimetype.contains("image")) {

            try {
                Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);

                intent.putExtra("Bitmap", bitmap);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else if (mimetype.contains("video")) {
                Bitmap bMap = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(uri.getPath(), MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);
                intent.putExtra("Bitmap", bMap);
            }
        startActivity(intent);
        }
}

private static String getMimeType(String fileUrl) {
    String extension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(fileUrl);
    return MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
}
```

Comment: `I have selected image or video from Mediastore.` Please start your post with the used intent. Then we know better what you are doing.

Comment: To get the MIME type associated with your `Uri`, call [`getType()` on a `ContentResolver`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver#getType(android.net.Uri)). You are assuming that the `Uri` contains a file extension, and that is not going to be the case all of the time.